Patching commands with complex argument structure
Thinking about this solution here, I thought it would be most appropriate to just patch \newtheorem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,cleveref}

\makeatletter
\let\@newtheorem\newtheorem
\RenewDocumentCommand\newtheorem{momo}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
        \IfNoValueTF{#4}{
            \@newtheorem{#1}{#3}
        }{
            \@newtheorem{#1}{#3}[#4]
        }
    }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#4}{
            \@newtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}
        }{
            \@newtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}
        }
        \AddToHook{env/#1/begin}{\crefalias{#2}{#1}}
    }
}

\newtheorem{thm}{theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{lemma}


\begin{document}
    \begin{lem}
        \label{lem}
    \end{lem}
    \cref{lem}
\end{document}

Luckily, \newtheorem has only two optional arguments, so I get 2^2 = 4 branches. But imagine there were three or even more optional arguents... How can I do this more concisely? I'd like to do something like
\let\@newtheorem\newtheorem
\RenewDocumentCommand\newtheorem{momo}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\AddToHook{env/#1/begin}{\crefalias{#2}{#1}}}%
    \@newtheorem[arguments as this command received them]
}

How to do that?
Edit: I realized that I forgot to add the star argument. You see how quickly this gets messy...

There is already a LaTeX \newtheorem (and a new version in latex-lab for the tagging project), a amsthm \newtheorem, a ntheorem \newtheorem, and one in thm-patch. Adding another definition will not improve the situation and get messy fast.

@UlrikeFischer What's the alternative? Adding a patch for every theorem enviroment  you define is also not very maintainable; especially if you work in a team and you have to tell the others that they have to use those patches.

What is the problem with simply writing also \AddToHook{env/lem/begin}{\crefalias{thm}{lem}} when you setup the theorem? Or define a new command \newtheoremwithcrefalias that does both. It costs you a few second but save you from hours of skimming the internet or tex.sx to find out why some patch has gone wrong.

Is \newtheorem a document command, or just a command?  I suspect that \IfNoValueTF requires some preprocessing of the arguments which is not provided by \newcommand.

Unless you have tens of \newtheorem declarations, it's much easier to just add \crefalias after them.
Anyway, I'd start from #4, because in that case we can completely ignore #2.
\NewCommandCopy{\amsthmnewtheorem}{\newtheorem}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\newtheorem}{smomo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% *-version
    \amsthmnewtheorem*{#2}{#4}%
  }{% normal version
    \IfNoValueTF{#5}{% no parent
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}{% no sibling
        \amsthmnewtheorem{#2}{#4}%
      }{% sibling
        \amsthmnewtheorem{#2}[#3]{#4}%
        \AddToHook{env/#2/begin}{\crefalias{#3}{#2}}%
      }%
    }{% with parent
      \amsthmnewtheorem{#2}{#4}[#5]%
    }%
  }%
}

The % aren't strictly necessary, because \newtheorem is usually called in the preamble, but it's good programming adding them where newlines could introduce spaces.

the amsthm-\newtheorem has also a star argument.

@UlrikeFischer Yes, but it's easy to fix.
